# How to insert date into new column based on initial date column

Tags: r, date

I have a data set where audio recorders where set up to be recorded. The technician recorded the date and time when the audio recorder was deployed. The technician then would return and swap batteries and memory cards in which the date would be recorded. So I have dates for each time a new memory was installed or as I think of it a date for when the recording started. I am struggling how to fill the "date_of_pickup" column based on knowing when they were deployed in sequential order. Basically I know the that the "date_of_deployment" for second observation per recorder is the date I need to insert into the "date_of_pickup".

```
data <- structure(list(recorder_id = c("smm03978", "smm03895", "smm03922", 
"smm03886", "smm03918", "smm04004", "smm03988", "smm03890", "smm03753", 
"smm03976", "smm03988", "smm04004", "smm03918", "smm03922", "smm03886", 
"smm03976", "smm03895", "smm03753", "smm04004", "smm03753", "smm03890", 
"smm03978", "smm03918", "smm03895", "smm03978", "smm03976", "smm04004", 
"smm03988", "smm03922", "smm03886", "smm03753", "smm03890"), 
    card_id = c("msd-1285\n", "msd-1326", "msd- 0198", "msd-1463", 
    "msd-1478", "msd-0722", "msd-1365", "msd-0807", "msd-0247", 
    "msd-1430", "msd-2683", NA, "msd-2687", "msd-0530", "msd-2682", 
    "msd-2688", "msd-2684", NA, "msd-2826", "msd-2830", "msd-2829", 
    "msd-2828", "msd-2885", "msd-2881", "msd-2878", "msd-2882", 
    "msd-2879", "msd-2877", "msd-2884", "msd-2880", "msd-2886", 
    "msd-2883"), date_of_deployment = c("2022-04-02 13:50:00", 
    "2022-04-02 14:03:00", "2022-04-02 14:41:00", "2022-04-02 14:58:00", 
    "2022-04-02 17:34:00", "2022-04-02 18:27:00", "2022-04-02 18:49:00", 
    "2022-04-03 15:19:00", "2022-04-03 15:32:00", "2022-04-03 16:06:00", 
    "2022-06-24 01:42:00", "2022-06-23 15:44:00", "2022-06-23 16:15:00", 
    "2022-06-23 17:17:00", "2022-06-23 17:32:00", "2022-06-23 18:00:00", 
    "2022-06-23 18:26:00", "2022-06-29 01:25:00", "2022-07-14 13:46:00", 
    "2022-07-15 17:30:00", "2022-07-15 17:48:00", "2022-07-15 18:27:00", 
    "2022-09-10 15:00:00", "2022-09-10 15:27:00", "2022-09-10 15:37:00", 
    "2022-09-10 16:03:00", "2022-09-10 16:38:00", "2022-09-10 16:45:00", 
    "2022-09-10 18:29:00", "2022-09-10 18:38:00", "2022-09-10 19:04:00", 
    "2022-09-10 19:14:00"), date_of_pickup = c("", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

data |> 
  mutate(date_of_deployment = readr::parse_datetime(date_of_deployment)) |> 
  group_by(recorder_id) |> 
  arrange(date_of_deployment) |> 
  mutate(date_of_pickup = nth(date_of_deployment, 2)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  arrange(recorder_id)

# A tibble: 32 × 4
   recorder_id card_id  date_of_deployment  date_of_pickup     
   <chr>       <chr>    <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 smm03753    msd-0247 2022-04-03 15:32:00 2022-06-29 01:25:00
 2 smm03753    NA       2022-06-29 01:25:00 2022-06-29 01:25:00
 3 smm03753    msd-2830 2022-07-15 17:30:00 2022-06-29 01:25:00
 4 smm03753    msd-2886 2022-09-10 19:04:00 2022-06-29 01:25:00
 5 smm03886    msd-1463 2022-04-02 14:58:00 2022-06-23 17:32:00
 6 smm03886    msd-2682 2022-06-23 17:32:00 2022-06-23 17:32:00
 7 smm03886    msd-2880 2022-09-10 18:38:00 2022-06-23 17:32:00
 8 smm03890    msd-0807 2022-04-03 15:19:00 2022-07-15 17:48:00
 9 smm03890    msd-2829 2022-07-15 17:48:00 2022-07-15 17:48:00
10 smm03890    msd-2883 2022-09-10 19:14:00 2022-07-15 17:48:00
# … with 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

EDIT: Maybe you want `mutate(date_of_pickup = lead(date_of_deployment))` instead of `mutate(date_of_pickup = nth(date_of_deployment, 2))`? This would result in this output:

```
# A tibble: 32 × 4
   recorder_id card_id  date_of_deployment  date_of_pickup     
   <chr>       <chr>    <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 smm03753    msd-0247 2022-04-03 15:32:00 2022-06-29 01:25:00
 2 smm03753    NA       2022-06-29 01:25:00 2022-07-15 17:30:00
 3 smm03753    msd-2830 2022-07-15 17:30:00 2022-09-10 19:04:00
 4 smm03753    msd-2886 2022-09-10 19:04:00 NA                 
 5 smm03886    msd-1463 2022-04-02 14:58:00 2022-06-23 17:32:00
 6 smm03886    msd-2682 2022-06-23 17:32:00 2022-09-10 18:38:00
 7 smm03886    msd-2880 2022-09-10 18:38:00 NA                 
 8 smm03890    msd-0807 2022-04-03 15:19:00 2022-07-15 17:48:00
 9 smm03890    msd-2829 2022-07-15 17:48:00 2022-09-10 19:14:00
10 smm03890    msd-2883 2022-09-10 19:14:00 NA                 
# … with 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Needs to be all the even ones, I think. You have the third and fourth instances picked up early.

Comment: That is close but you are populating the second for all three re-deployments. For recorder "smm03753" the second observation for "date_of_pickup" should be "2022-07-15". And so on ... basically the date_of_deployment needs to be shifted up one row and moved to date_of_pickup per recorder_id

Comment: Ok - i'm a little bit confused because you said "Basically I know the that the "date_of_deployment" for second observation per recorder is the date I need to insert into the "date_of_pickup"." I'm not catching the logic between that and this comment.

Comment: @Phil using lead() is exactly what I needed. Sorry for the confusion in my post but thank you for showing me the process to get there with tidyverse